# Из этой строки(AAaaSSsbBbhhhKkKKKiiI) надо получить эту(A2S2K4) не использую методы(типо: sort(), map() и тому подобное)

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, задание-на-собеседовании

Из этой строки(AAaaSSsbBbhhhKkKKKiiI) надо получить эту(A2S2K4) не использую методы(типо: sort(), map() и тому подобное)

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```js
let str = "AAaaSSsbBbhhhKkKKKiiI"
let obj = {};
for (let symb of str)
    if (symb.toLocaleUpperCase() === symb)
        if (obj[symb])
            ++obj[symb]
        else
            obj[symb] = 1;
    
let res = "";
for (let key in obj)
    res += obj[key] > 1 ? key + obj[key] : "";

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

На будущее, задачи на собеседования выполняйте самостоятельно.

```js
function test(str) {
  str = str.replace(/[a-z]/g, '').match(/([A-Z])\1+/g);
  let s = [];
  str.forEach(e => {
    s.push(e[0]+''+e.length);
  });
  return s.join('');
}

console.info(test('AAaaSSsbBbhhhKkKKKiiI'));
```

Comment: это вариант "не использую методы(типо: sort(), map() и тому подобное)"?

Comment: @AzizUmarov, не знаю, честно, в "подобное" что можно внести? Всё кроме `forEach`?

Comment: Лично моё субъектвное мнение forEach сидит вместе  sort(), map()

Comment: @AzizUmarov, теперь даже интересно стало, как ещё можно реализовать это)

Comment: Выше пример чем вас не устраивает. Банальный цикл

Comment: @AzizUmarov, хороший пример, но интересует более короткая запись)

Comment: Мне ровно, про100 требования не мои. Лично я таккие вопросы не отвечаю из тех же соображений